# Opening PDF file in SWT Browser - XulRunner default viewer

Tags: java, pdf, swt, xulrunner

**Situation:**

1. My RCP application uses XulRunner
2. System has two installed PDF viewers (Acrobat, Gimp)
3. Firefox has Gimp set as default viewer
4. I want to make my SWT Browser composite in RCP application ignore default viewer and use Acrobat if it is installed
5. If it is not, I want to use default viewer

**Question:**

1. Can I achieve this by (temporarily) setting some XulRunner or System property in my application?

Comment: What operating system is that RCP application running on?

Comment: only Windows, nothing else

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Process` in Java and execute the below command line to open PDFs in Adobe Acrobat Reader forever.

```
start "" /max "ExecutablePathAdobeAcrobat.exe" /A "pagemode=FullScreen" "PDFFilePath.pdf"
```

Comment: thanks for answer,but this I couldn't do. I needed to display the PDF in embedded Browser composite, so starting independent process was not a possibility. This issue was found indoors, all customers use acrobat, so we did not make anything with it so far. But still, an interesting topic

Answer (score 1):

Check this link : 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-built-pdf-viewer-and-use-another-viewer

I am pretty sure there should be a way to codefully disable the gimp or whatever built-in app the firefox uses. you might need to use some APIs that modify preferences in Firefox